# How to return only aggregation results not hits in elasticsearch query dsl

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am writing a query dsl in python using http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io

and I have following code

```
search.aggs.bucket('per_ts', 'terms', field='ts')\
            .bucket('load_time', 'percentiles', field='total_req', percents=[99])


response = search.execute()
```

This works fine but it also returns `hits`. But I don't want `hits`

In curl query mode I can get what I want by doing `size:0` in

```
GET /twitter/tweet/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "my_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I couldn't find a way where I can use `size = 0` in query dsl.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the code of elasticsearch-dsl-py/search.py [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/elasticsearch_dsl/search.py)

```
s = Search().query(...).extra(from_=0, size=25)
```

This statement should work.